# Posting a form spanning two table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a case where I've created a table with entities. 
Every first row is a clickable summary row and every other is a hidden information row which can be expanded with input fields and a submit button to allow the user to update the entity. The summary row has several columns.
The solution I have now for updating this, is a form in the information row, the inputs and a submit button.

Pug notations describing the scenario for one entity though there's gonna be many more in a real world scenario:

```
table
  tr.summary
    td.name
      input(type="text",name="name", value="The name")
    td.moreData
      input(type="text",name="moreData", value="testing")
    td.evenMore
  tr.info
    td(cospan=3)
      form(action="api/update/")
        input(type="text",name="customer")
        button(type="submit") Send
```

My problem now is that I also want to include the inputs in the header row in my post data.

I also need to say that I've already intercepted the normal behavior for this submit, to allow JQuery to do a PUT request instead of the normal POST and also to keep the user on the same page.

My two solution alternatives are now the following:

1. In my javascript intercept code, programmatically include the inputs from the row before. This solution would require maybe 1-5 extra lines of code, but would break the semantic of my HTML because the form doesn't include all fields that are being sent.
2. Update the HTML in the summary row, to have only one row with a table inside containing the previous summary row and the information row. This solution would allow me to wrap the inner table with a form and there for keep the semantics. But it would look horrible..

Any suggestions on which solution would be the best, or if there are any other solutions possible to this?

Comment: The _correct_ solution in my opinion would be to correctly structure your HTML so that all `input` elements are within the `form`. Anything else would be a hack or a workaround.

Comment: I got a tip on another channel about an attribute that's new in HTML5. The attribute is on input element and is "form" which declare which form it belongs to. I tried it, and it seems to work perfectly so for. Hopefully I don't run into any problems with it later.

Comment: Nice. You learn something every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a tip on another channel about an attribute that's new in HTML5. The attribute is on input element and is "form" which declare which form it belongs to. I tried it, and it seems to work perfectly so for. Hopefully I don't run into any problems with it later.
The solution doesn't work in any versions of IE, but since I'm using jQuery to do the posting and not using the native behavior, it should work in my scenario but may not work in others.

```
table
  tr.summary
    td.name
      input(type="text",name="name", value="The name", form="entity_1934")
    td.moreData
      input(type="text",name="moreData", value="testing", form="entity_1934")
    td.evenMore
  tr.info
    td(cospan=3)
      form(action="api/update/", id="entity_1934)
        input(type="text",name="customer")
        button(type="submit") Send
```